# Sum of eigenvalues is nonpositive

Tags: linear-algebra, inequalities, eigenvalues

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive semidefinite $n \times n$ matrix. How can I show that the sum of the largest $n-k+1$ eigenvalues of $A - k\cdot \textrm{diag}(A)$ is nonpositive, for any $k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$?

For example, equality holds for $k = 1$ and for $k = n$ when $\textrm{rank}(A) = 1$. I have ad-hoc proofs for $k \in \{2,n-1\}$ and have checked it with random matrices on numpy for other values of $k$.

We can reduce it to the case when $A$ has rank 1 by convexity, and in that case we can write down the characteristic polynomial using the matrix determinant lemma. It doesn't seem to help.

There also seems to be a more general version: if the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_n$, then for any $m \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ we have $\lambda_m + \cdots + \lambda_{n - m(k-1)} \le 0$. The problem above is the special case $m = 1$. When $m = n/k$ this means $\lambda_{n/k} \le 0$, which is not hard to show by looking at the eigenvalues of $D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$ where $D = \textrm{diag}(A)$. I don't know how to solve it for any other $m$.

Comment: I think a possible reformulation is: Let $P$ be a projection onto a $d$-dimensional subspace. Is it then true that $M\ge 0$, with $M=-P+(n-d+1)\textrm{diag}\: P$? Not sure though if this gets us any closer to a solution.

Comment: Hi Christian. It seems like while the sum of the largest eigenvalues is nonpositive, they are not all always nonpositive.

Comment: Yes, but note that I'm only considering projections in my reformulation, so there is no immediate contradiction to what you're saying. (The argument establishing the equivalence was quite simple, but of course I still may have made a mistake somewhere.)

Comment: To make this more concrete: If my $M$ is not positive definite and $\langle v, Mv\rangle <0$, then I believe $A=\langle v, \cdot \rangle v$ gives a counterexample to your claim, for $k=n-d$ (and test on vectors spanning $R(P)$).

Comment: Ah, yes, you’re right that these are equivalent. I’m not sure if we can also state the more general version with $m$ in terms of projections.

Comment: I believe I have figured it out, but are you still interested?

Comment: Hi fedja, I figured out how to do the original problem, but still don't know about the extension (for $m > 1$). I am still pretty interested in that, if you know how to do it (even just a sketch)

Comment: Alas, so far I can do only the original one :-(. But I'll think a bit more of it :-)